# Excel conditional drop down lists causing massive file size

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, compression

I have an excel file which relies heavily on data validation. There are about 20 drop down lists per row. One column has a 35 formatting conditions. One column is a conditional drop down list (using `INDIRECT`). There are about 500 rows formatted like this.

The file is 23Mb, and although 500 rows have been pre-"formatted/validated", no rows have data entered. I gather Excel isn't compressing or otherwise making use of the similarity in logic between the rows.

My question: can I reduce the file size in any way? I'm supposed to be emailing this as an attachment to the users, because they're on a different WAN.

Note: This is a precursor mock-up of a web app form; I'm trying to test user responses to get a feel for what types of data they enter before creating the app. All the users are in Windows environments. I know InfoPath would be better designed for this task, but unfortunately for the delay haggling with the company's IT team to set up the infrastructure, I may as well just code the web app in the first place.

Comment: So you want to reduce the file size just so you can transfer it easily? Have you tried an archiver?

Comment: That's a good idea. gzipping it gets it down to 2Mb (as does deleting the pre-validated rows and writing a note for users to copy old rows into new rows and changing the data).

Comment: Ok, good simple solution; thanks. If you paste it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really simple solution to reduce the file size just for the purpose of mailing it would be to compress it using any popular archiving utility.